# Is there a twitter client which automatically saves all tweets I see?

Tags: ubuntu, archiving, twitter

I'd like every tweet about certain topics saved, so tweets with a certain hashtag, word, user, etc.

To reiterate, if I see a tweet, I want to save it forever and ever.

I'm running Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twapper Keeper](http://twapperkeeper.com/index.php) is able to archive hashtags online.